# How to handle CloudFront redirects with Lambda edge function

Tags: redirect, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Is it better to use 302 status and redirect header or Internally call the the target URL and return the result?

I have to write a lambda function to handle CloudFront redirect to a different URL. I have two options to do this:

1. Use redirect headers and return from lambda function. This can create issue of preflight requests.
2. Within lambda function, call the target URL and return the result

Which approach is better? And any possible issues which can happen?

Comment: I don't think it will affect preflight request, even if it does, you can write your program to redirect only if "method": "OPTIONS", does't match. a 302 callback or returning the complete result in viewer request should work for you but it'll hit lambda for all the requests, it's better to serve the redirection from the origin so CloudFront can cache it and save lambda execution.

Comment: So by redirection from the origin you mean to use option 2 in my question? Where we call the target and return result and don't do any 302 redirection? Are there any possible issues which I need to take care of with this approach?

Comment: No, I was saying not to ask lambda and backend to contact to the target and fetch the answer but instead ask the client to do it but configure redirection (302) from the backend not  at the viewer request.